# Setting index of TableView in javafx

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, indexing, tableview

I'm making a program that adds data to a table in a while loop that runs x amount of times. In the while loop, I have this code:

```
 data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                      new Songs(artist, title, album, genre, year)
                );
```

My problem is that every time I run the while loop it changes the data in the first row of the table. Is there any way to set the index of the table so it'll write to the next empty spot?

Thanks!

Comment: The line of code you posted creates a new list. You probably (we don't really know since we have no context for this code) want to add the new song to the existing list.

Comment: I have five TableColumn's for the table, and each of the items in the 'Songs' table that I have defined go into each one of those categories. My while loop is checking audio files and getting the metadata from them and writing them into the table. My problem is because of the while statement, if I get the properties of two songs, it will write to the first row of the table again and I am wondering about how to tell it to write to the second row while still using my while loop.

Comment: Well, as I said, assuming the tiny code snippet you posted is in the `while` loop, you would be creating an entire new list on every iteration. You (presumably) want to create just one list, and add an element to it on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: So how do I do this operation without creating a new list every time? I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Comment: Just add the song to the list?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new list on every iteration of the loop, create one list and add the song to it on each iteration:

```
data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

while (/* ... */) {
    // ...

    data.add(new Song(...));

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going about it the wrong way before. Appreciate it!